# What do (correct) ANN bias and weights look like on TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, tensorboard

I'm just trying to understand why my loss function plots are looking so tragic. Please forgive the broad question, but hopefully the answer is simple.

loss plots:
[image: loss plots]

When looking at TensorBoard while training, what shape should the distribution plots and histograms take, when the thing is actually learning correctly?

bias and weight graphs:
[image: bias and weight graphs]

My understanding was the bias distribution should be trending towards zero, as adjustments become smaller, and weights should (ideally) have a fully even distribution. Be grateful if anyone could explain that better.

This is the LSTM net I think is having trouble converging:
[image: tensorboard graph]

Comment: Thinking this problem is better described as a gradient descent issue, evidenced by the biases and weights not converging as they should. 

I've improved value loss significantly by using tf.contrib.opt.NadamOptimizer instead of AdamOptimizer, and adjusting the alpha value, but still seem to be a loooong way from converging on this data :-/